# Call method in UIViewController from NSObject?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard, xcode4.3, pass-data

I'm new to iOS development so please bear with me.
Say I have a basic method in a UIViewController that only NSLogs the words "hi".
how would I call this method from an NSObject class?

It's easy to call methods in an NSObject class from a ViewController but it doesn't seem to work both ways.

I have been using the below code to call a method from an NSObject class from a view controller.

```
 SecondClass *secondClass = [[SecondClass alloc]init];
 [secondClass displayTheNSLog];
```

but if I reverse this code so that "SecondClass" would be a View Controller the method doesent get called.

I'm using Xcode 4.3, ARC, and storyboards.

-Thanks for all the help!

-Shredder2794

Comment: I would create a singleton logging class that the view controller checks periodically for updates.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options here:

1. Have you declared the displayTheNSLog method in the view controllers .h file? In order for other classes to know about methods you have added to your view controller class you need to do this like so:

   -(void) displayTheNSLog;

somewhere in the .h interface.

1. Are you sure that the method you are calling the view controllers method from in your nsobject subclass is being invoked by the iOS system? If not try creating the object in your view controller class and calling the method on the object that contains the call to the view controller displayTheNSLog method.